# Access elements from cells arrays in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, cell-array

Say I have a cell arrays (named as 'data') as below:

```
'k0'    'k1'    'Agg'   'RH'    'AQ'    'fr'    'frac'  'Cel'   'R_A'   'Tot'   'AO'
1.15    1.1574  1.50    0.99    0.090   3.45    1.10    1   11x2 double     11x2 double  11x2 double
```

How do I get the last element or any element that I desire from the columns

```
'frac'  'Cel'   'R_A'
11x2 double 11x2 double  11x2 double
```

I tried using data{:,9}(end) to get the last element from the column 'frac', but not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that `data{:,9}` returns two elements.

```
data{:,9}

%   ans = 
%       'R_A'
%
%   ans = 
%       11 x 2 double
```

As a result, indexing with `(end)` after that isn't going to work. It looks like you only want the *second* row and not all of them. So something like this should work:

```
data{2,9}(end)
```

If you *do* want the last element from all things in column 9, then you'd need to use `cellfun` to do this for you.

```
values = cellfun(@(x)x(end), data(:,9), 'uniform', 0);
```

Comment: Thanks! What if I have multiple rows?

Comment: @Orangeblue The last line of my answer shows how you would do this.